# Disprove: for all $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ and $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, if $g\circ f$ is injective then $g$ is injective.

Tags: functions

I realize this question is similar to existing questions, but the domain and codomain being specifically $\mathbb{Z}$ makes this a little tougher.

To rewrite the original question:

Prove $\exists f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, $g \circ f$ is injective $\land$ $g$ is not injective.

I've tried a lot of different combinations for $f$ and $g$, but it doesn't seem to work. To pose an actual question, which functions satisfy this?

Comment: The key realization here is that if $g\circ f$ is injective, that implies that $g$ must be injective on the image of $f$. To find a counterexample, you need $f$ to be non-surjective, and then construct a $g$ so that $g(a)=g(b)$ for some $a,b$ *not* in the image of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two functions that work are $ f(x) = 2x $ and $g(x) = \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor $. g is not injective because $ g(2) = g(3) $

Comment: Nice example, very natural.

Answer (score 0):

We need $f$ to be non-surjective, so that $g$ can exhibit dodgy behaviour on the complement of the image of $f$. But we want $f$ to be injective, to increase the probability that $g \circ f$ will be injective. In summary: $f$ should be injective but non-surjective.

Do define $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by: $$f(n) = \begin{cases} 2n & n \geq 0 \\ -2n-1 & n < 0\end{cases}$$

And define $g : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by: $$g(n) = |n|$$

We observe that $f$ is injective and that $g(f(n)) = f(n),$ hence $g \circ f$ is injective. But $g$ is not.